# Sync position of two DIVs

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I have a case where I need to position one DIV right under another, sort of like a tooltip. It has to be in a separate container (portals pattern). My problem is, if I do so in requestAnimationFrame — at the time of the callback if I call getBoundingClientRect to figure out positions, I get old position from the previous frame, new one is not yet calculated. At least it seems so to me. So when user scrolls the page, sometimes the position is visibly incorrect for a frame. You have to scroll fast up and down in Chrome to notice it. It gets worse in IE11 where it is incorrect for EVERY frame, lagging one frame behind, even in following CSS animation.

I have created a simple codepen where I try to make dropdown follow a moving "duck":
https://codepen.io/waterplea/pen/gdwQGK

```
var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
var duck = document.querySelector('.duck');
var host = document.querySelector('.host');

requestAnimationFrame(position);

function position() {
  var duckRect = duck.getBoundingClientRect();
  var hostRect = host.getBoundingClientRect();

  dropdown.style.top = duckRect.top + duckRect.height - hostRect.top + 'px';
  dropdown.style.left = duckRect.left - hostRect.left + 'px';

  requestAnimationFrame(position);
}
```

Codepens do not work in IE, so here's a link for working debug view to try and see the lag in IE:
https://s.codepen.io/waterplea/debug/gdwQGK/DqrDdKgDjVXr

So my question is — how can I make my DIVs be in sync? How can I run my code when upcoming position of the DIV is already known?

**EDIT:** Here's a screen capture from Mac where it is always reproducible:
https://jmp.sh/v/KJ9ndWhBPPQem49wfChm

Comment: The codepen looks fine to me in Chrome no matter what I do. If you're having trouble with scrolling, maybe try switching to absolute coords instead?

Comment: Looks like it works fine on a 1080p monitor with 60fps Chrome on Windows. But on Mac or on my 30fps 4K monitor it is reproducible even on Windows Chrome. Attached a screen recording from Mac. The problem is not about aboslute coordinates, I need a universal solution to the issue.

Comment: Using css (if possible) to accomplish this effect will net you a much better experience. For what it's worth, I can't reproduce on OSX Chrome, but I do get weird behavior on resize. Also, try the "ticking" method from this link: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/

Comment: Thanks. But that still would happen after a reflow, seems like there is no way to do what I want to do. I know CSS would be better, but this is a portals pattern where dropdowns/tooltips/popups are displayed in a separate layer above isolated stack context, which is really great to avoid overflow: hidden or z-index issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may make the original host invisible and have two overlays above it. The first one would duplicate the host's content (this time visible) and the second one would be your duck payload. Then these two overlays should scroll in sync.

The transparent host needs to exist to establish its natural size that you can read later. And if the size is known, you may use an empty `div` instead of it.

The pair would still scroll one frame behind the page content, but at least the overlay would not obstruct the visible host that badly.